# How do I remove an entry from List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> based on just the key?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a KeyValurPair myList. How do I remove an entry based on the key? How should I use the myList.Remove method? I am not using a dictionary because need myList to be the Datasource of a Bindingsource.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

string key = "@index";
```

..
..
..

```
myList.Remove( i am lost here )
```

Thanks in adavnce,
VRPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [List.RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.asp). You can pass in a predicate which checks the key value.
Example:

```
myList.RemoveAll(kvp => kvp.Key == "@index");
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot codekaizen. If I got it right, is the predicate as a delegate, except that it returns only boolean values?